# Java Microservice to train AI model Problem

Tags: java, python, model, artificial-intelligence, microservices

I've already built a server which contains several spring boot microservices, and we've also wrote a python script to train AI models.

Now we want to build a service into this server to check our data at a specific time every day and run the python script to train the model.

Is there a good way to design this service? Do I need to call the Python script from Java or is there better ways? Is there any libraries you recommend?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have microservices and your working code is in Python, you should consider having a Python service to run the code natively instead of encapsulating it into Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling python service at specific time can be achieved in different ways, however which option you decide depends on the needs of the application. Few options you can explore:-

1. Create spring scheduled service that will run automatically refer to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) for details.
2. Creat CRON job on the server that will call the python service. Refer here for [details](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/amp/) of CRON job

Comment: Hi Ravik, thanks for your response! I finally decided to use CRON job.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to integrate your training code more closely into your JVM microservices, you could have a look at [Jython](https://www.jython.org/).